# Losing Data at TCP transfer

Tags: sockets, tcp, avr

My problem is losing Data over my TCP Data transfer.

I've built a homemade AVR based web-server (or at least trying to).

I'm able to communicate with the client PC (my PC), and I'm able to send a few HTML lines (total data <100 bytes), no problem there.

But when I want to sent my basic home page (~1KB), I'm only getting in WireShark 181bytes of data.

I suspect the problem lies in the construction of the TCP.

data below are in hex format

From client(my PC):

```
sequence number: de db c7 b1

ack number: 00 0a 00 0b
```

From server(AVR):

```
sequence number: 00 0a 00 0b

ack number: de b6 c9 18
```

Total TCP Length: 935byte, IP and TCP header 20-20 byte

What settings did I set wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!

```
ENC28J60_CS();
ENC28J60_CMD(WCR,ETXNDL);
SPIWR(package_length);
SPIWR(16+(package_length>>8));
ENC28J60_DS();
```

package_length is a integer, so is the ETXNDL(register).
Until now the second SPIWR() function sent only the value 16: SPIWR(16);
So the problem was, I never added the high-byte of the package_length to the 16, so the chip always sended 1-255 byte long packages.

why 16?
RX buffer starts at 0x0000, and ends at 0x0fff.
TX buffer starts at 0x1000, and ends at 0x1fff.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a stream and there is no guarantee that each send will result in exactly one recv. You need to call send repeatedly until all bytes are sent, and on the other end you need to recv repeatedly as well, appending new data to the end of a buffer on each subsequent successful recv... You cannot ignore the return codes from the send/recv calls, you must use it to know how much data is sent/recvd.

Comment: I think I has not clear in my problem.
I have a page that is ~1KB big, so it fits in one TCP packet.
This packet is generated via AVR correctly, but somewhere during transfer (LAN) only 181byte is received. I know packets can be lost, but parts of a packet? And in LAN? Oh and the size what I'm getting is always 181byte.

Comment: There is no such thing as a TCP packet, only TCP stream. In TCP you can safely ignore MTU. But you cannot ignore the return code from send and recv.